# Curl POST fields not being posted

Tags: php, curl

I've verified that `$requestDom->saveXml()` is returning valid XML but at the destination URL I have print_r($_POST) and it doesn't receive anything.  Am I missing something here? :-\

```
    $connection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'xml' => $requestDom->saveXml()
    ));
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); //with or without this option, it doesn't work
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sample.com');

    $response = curl_exec($connection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I've discovered that the proper method to post xml to a destination URL is to....

```
$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestDom->saveXml());
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); //with or without this option, it doesn't work
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sample.com');

$response = curl_exec($connection);
```

And then on the file receiving this information, use:

```
            $post = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $request = simplexml_load_string($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the problem. Ask for help in the #php.pecl channel on EFnet.